# Update a join of two tables based on the third table values

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables.

Table1: Type Table

```
id |before_id | after_id | 
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 20     |    17|
```

Table2: History Table

```
+----+---------+----------+----------+-------------+--------
| id | user_id | start_at            | end_at              | 
+----+---------+----------+----------+-------------+--------
|  1 |     2013 | 2022-11-07 00:21:30 | 2022-11-07 04:06:00 |
```

Table3: Mapping table

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 17 |    1 |
| 18 |    2 |
| 19 |    3 |
| 20 |    4 |
| 21 |    5 |
| 22 |    6 |
| 23 |    7 |
```

I wanted to join Table 1 and Table 2 on their id, and then update the Table1.before_id and Table1.after_id with the mappings shown in the Table 3. As shown in Table3, the before_id= 20 should be updated to 4, and after_id = 17 should be updated to 1.

IS it possible to do this in one single query? I was thinking of joining the Table1 and Table2 and then create a temporary table, and then update the values by referring to the Mapping table. How should I do that?

The final table should look like that

```
id |before_id | after_id | user_id | start_at            | end_at 

|  1 | 4     |    1  |      2013 |   2022-11-07 00:21:30 | 2022-11-07 04:06:00
```

PS: The tables except the mapping table are huge so I would also prefer if the solution is efficient

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to get answers that actually work in your DBMS.

Comment: Please don't use the word `UPDATE` when you only want to select data. `UPDATE` suggests table updates to us SQL developers.

Comment: As you can see from the two answers you got, the task is ambiguous. Do you only write a query to get the result you are showing or do you want to alter the contents of the type table for good and then get rid of the mapping table?

Comment: I just wrote the query to get the results instead of updating the table. All the tables are important so I can't delete and alter any tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the tables. The mapping table must be joined twice, because you want two different rows per type row. And when joining a table twice you must use table aliases, so as to tell one row from the other:

```
select
  h.id,
  mb.type as type_before,
  ma.type as type_after,
  h.user_id,
  h.start_at,
  h.end_at
from history h
join type t on t.id = h.id
join mapping mb on mb.id = t.before_id
join mapping ma on ma.id = t.after_id;
```

Comment: The question simply wants to `update` `Table1.before_id` and `Table1.after_id` to their corresponding `type` based on the `id` in `Table3` matching the old values of `before_id` and `after_id`, respectively.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad: That may explain the downvote I got. And you may be right. But maybe not. After re-reading the request, to me it still looks like they just want the simple query I am showing.

Comment: I did not down-vote your answer, but that could have been the reason. I think there is an actual need for an update because the question explicitly says it: "As shown in Table3, the before_id= 20 should be updated to 4, and after_id = 17 should be updated to 1."

Comment: @Lajos Arpad: Well, if I am not mistaken, this is basicly what the OP thinks might be an approach to get to the esired result, but what they actually only want to achieve is select the data: "Is it possible to do this in one single query?" Well, let's just wait for them to come back and check our answers ;-)

Comment: I agree with you that we cannot know for sure which is it. I'm only 99% sure that an actual update is needed and the op simply misphrased the part you have quoted :)

Comment: But I will upvote this answer if it turns out to address the issue rather than mine (of course, only if I do not forget to do so)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I actually do not want to affect the existing tables. The answer by @ThorstenKettner works well for me. Thanks Lajos for help too. Both answers worked but for my current use case, I am not supposed to update any table.

Comment: Thorsten, it turns out that you were right all along. Congrats for that and you fully deserve my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
update Table1
join Table2
on Table1.id = Table2.id
join Table3 bef
on Table1.before_id = bef.id
join Table3 aft
on Table1.after_id = aft.id
set Table1.before_id = bef.`type`,
    Table2.after_id = aft.`type`
```

Explanation:

- I presume MySQL now, let me know if you use a different RDBMS
- I join with `Table2` `on` `id` match for a reason unkown to me (you expressed this desire in the question, but did not explain the reason for it, so I presume this is a valid expectation)
- I join with `Table3` to get the `before_id` mapping and again with `Table3` to get the `after_id` mapping, using the aliases of `bef` and `aft`, respectively
- I do the filtering via `join` conditions because inner join is involved
- at the end I update `before_id` and `after_id` to their corresponding `type`

Let me know if this fulfills your need. If not, please explain whether something's missing from this update.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using MySQL. Sorry I might have not clearly defined my use case. I don't want to update the main tables (all three tables are main) that's why I was preparing a temp table. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ethicalguy happy to help!